# How to make anchors on page numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, eso-pic

This is an extention of [How to jump into any page in an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600005/how-to-jump-into-any-page-in-an-article/600040#600040)

I want to make an anchor on each page number with which clicking the page number will jump to the related page.

But the following MWE show that all anchors are in wrong positions(please see the attached figure).

Anyone have proposal or solution of this issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,ifthen,eso-pic,picture,xparse,lastpage,refcount,tikz,hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{
 \newcounter{totalpage}
 \setcounter{totalpage}{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{%
   \put(0.5\paperwidth-0.5\marginparwidth,0.5\textheight) {%
      \scalebox{0.7} {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]%
          \foreach \i in {1,...,\thetotalpage}{%
            \ifnum\value{page}=\i\relax%
               \tikzset{pn/.style={fill=red,font=\bfseries}}
            \else%
               \tikzset{pn/.style={fill=gray,opacity=0.5}}%
            \fi%
            \hyperlink{page.\i}{%   
            \path[radius=0.5cm,scale=1,text=white,pn](0,-\i) circle node[scale=1.5]{\i};
          }%\hyperlink  
          }%\foreach
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%\scalebox
    }%put
}}
first page
\clearpage
second page
\clearpage
third page    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue the other day and the answers to this question here helped me out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/making-tikz-nodes-hyperlinkable

Comment: Essentially, put the hyperlink inside the node, instead of the node within the hyperlink.

Comment: I tried this: `node[scale=1.5]{\hyperlink{page.\i}{\i}}` in my code. It does work, but only on the number. How to make the anchor on all the circle area? Would you please show me a MWE

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600053/113546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code inspired from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36111/161015

> There's a new TikZ style called `hyperlink node=<target>` that takes a
> hypertarget reference. It works by measuring the node it is supplied
> to, and then placing a new invisible node on top of that. The new node
> has the content `\hyperlink{<target>}{\phantom{\rule{<width of node>}{<height of node>}}`, so it has the same size as the original
> node, but the whole area is clickable.

[image: w]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newcounter{totalpage}
    \setcounter{totalpage}{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}
        \tikzset{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36111/161015
        hyperlink node/.style={%
            alias=sourcenode,
            append after command={%
                let     \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2} in
                node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}          
            }
        },
    NOlink/.style={circle, draw, fill=gray!30, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    LINKED/.style={circle, draw, fill=green!40, very thick, minimum size=7mm,font=\bfseries, hyperlink node=\i},
    }
    
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{%
            \put(0.5\paperwidth-1.5\marginparwidth,0.5\textheight){%
                    \scalebox{0.7} {%
                        \parbox{7mm}{%
                        \foreach \i in {1,...,\thetotalpage}{%
                            \ifnum\value{page}=\i%
                        \tikz{\node [NOlink] {\i};\node[] () [below =8pt] {};}  %plus node spacer               
                            \else%
                        \tikz{\node [LINKED] {\i};\node[] () [below =8pt] {};}
                            \fi%            
                        }%\foreach
                }       
                }%\scalebox
            }%put
        \AtPageCenter{\hypertarget{\thepage}{}}
    }
}


first page  
\clearpage  
second page 
\clearpage  
third page    
\end{document}
```